What is the version compatibility of spring boot 2.6.0 and snowflake-jdbc driver?
I need to upgrade the snowflake jdbc driver in  my spring boot 2.6.0 application. I not able to find which snowflake jdbc driver version is most compatible for spring boot 2.6.0 version .Any help or reference is appreciated .
